# How would I write this using set comprehension?

Tags: python, set-comprehension

It works using a regular loop but I want it to work using set comprehension.

```
def setComp():
    result = set()
    for n in range(1, 101):
        x = n
        y = x**2
        if y%x == 0 and y%3 == 0:
            tup = (x,y)
            result.add(tup)
    return result

print(setComp())
```

This is what I have:

```
result = { x = n, y = x**2 for n in range(1, 101)if n%x == 0 and y%3 == 0 }
```

Comment: `y%x` will always be `0`. `y` is `x` squared.

Comment: You could skip the `y%3 == 0` test and just iterate over `range(3, 101, 3)`, too.

Comment: Comprehensions can only contain expressions, not statements, and Python assignments aren't expressions. So I don't think you can do this as a comprehension.

Comment: @Barmar unless you know the walrus :P

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
{(x, x**2) for x in range(1,101) if (x**2) %3 == 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-liner `list` comprehension

```
result = {(n, n ** 2) for n in range(1, 101) if (n ** 2 % n) == 0 and ((n ** 2) % 3 == 0)}
```

However the downside to this is that is has to calculate `n**2` three times during the comprehensive. For better performance, generate two `list` and use `zip` in the comprehension

```
xs = range(1, 101)
ys = [n ** 2 for n in q]
reuslts = {(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys) if (y % x) == 0 and (y % 3 == 0)}
```

The latter option provides better performance than the former

```
import timeit

xs = range(1, 101)
ys = [n ** 2 for n in xs]


def l():
    return {(n, n ** 2) for n in xs if (n ** 2 % n) == 0 and ((n ** 2) % 3 == 0)}


def f():
    return {(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys) if (y % x) == 0 and (y % 3 == 0)}


print('l', timeit.timeit(l))
>>> 68.20

print('f', timeit.timeit(f))
>>> 19.67
```